# ¿Cómo puedo usar la getline en mi código? C++

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PELICULAS {

public:
    string titulo;
    string clasificacion;
    string duracion;
    string horario;
    string costo;
    string formato;

    void mostrar ();
    void capturar ();

}da;

void PELICULAS :: capturar(){
    cout<< "DATOS DE LAS PELICULAS"<< endl<<endl;
    cout<< "Titulo de la pelicula: ";
    cin>>da.titulo;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<< "Clasificacion: "<<endl;
    cin>>da.clasificacion;
    cout<< "Duracion: "<<endl;
    cin>>da.duracion;
    cout<<"Horario: "<<endl;
    cin>>da.horario;
    cout<<"Costo: "<<endl;
    cin>>da.costo;
    cout<<"Formato: "<<endl;
    cin>>da.formato;
};

void PELICULAS::mostrar(){
    cout<<"PELICULA EXISTENTE"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<da.titulo<< endl;
    cout<< da.clasificacion<< endl;
    cout<< da.duracion<<endl;
    cout<<da.horario<<endl;
    cout<<da.costo<<endl;
    cout<<da.formato<<endl;
};

int main(){
    PELICULAS datos;
    datos.capturar();

    PELICULAS datos1;
    datos.mostrar();

       system("PAUSE");
       system("CLS");
       cout<<endl;

   return 0;


}
```

Tengo un problema con mi código, ya que cuando trato de escribir una película con todo y los espacios no los guarda en "Titulo de la película" sino que lo divide y las pone en las demás variables, he estado investigando viendo tutoriales y encontré el getline, pero ¿Cómo puedo usarlo en mi código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi lo resolvi yo. Cambiando el tipo de dato de `string` a tipo `char` y cada variable la conviertes en un arreglo. Luego, donde quieres introducir los datos (cin) seria con `cin.getline(variable, tamaño del arreglo, y cuando terminaria)`. Luego de cada registro, agregar un `cin.ignore()` para limpiar el buffer que deja. Tambien agrege la libreria  al comienzo del codigo.

**Aqui te dejo el codigo:**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PELICULAS {

public:
    char titulo[100];
    char clasificacion[100];
    char duracion[100];
    char horario[100];
    char costo[100];
    char formato[100];

    void mostrar ();
    void capturar ();

}da;

void PELICULAS :: capturar(){
    cout<< "DATOS DE LAS PELICULAS"<< endl<<endl;
    cout<< "Titulo de la pelicula: "; 
    cin.getline(da.titulo,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<< "Clasificacion: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(da.clasificacion,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cout<< "Duracion: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(da.duracion,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Horario: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(da.horario,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Costo: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(da.costo,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Formato: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(da.formato,100,'\n');
    cin.ignore();
};

void PELICULAS::mostrar(){
    cout<<"PELICULA EXISTENTE"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<da.titulo<< endl;
    cout<< da.clasificacion<< endl;
    cout<< da.duracion<<endl;
    cout<<da.horario<<endl;
    cout<<da.costo<<endl;
    cout<<da.formato<<endl;
};

int main(){
    PELICULAS datos;
    datos.capturar();

    PELICULAS datos1;
    datos.mostrar();

       system("PAUSE");
       system("CLS");
       cout<<endl;

   return 0;


}
```

Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

aqui te dejo el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class PELICULAS {

public:
    string titulo;
    string clasificacion;
    string duracion;
    string horario;
    string costo;
    string formato;

    void mostrar ();
    void capturar ();

}da;

void PELICULAS :: capturar(){
    cout<< "DATOS DE LAS PELICULAS"<< endl<<endl;
    cout<< "Titulo de la pelicula: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.titulo);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<< "Clasificacion: "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.clasificacion);
    cout<< "Duracion: "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.duracion);
    cout<<"Horario: "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.horario);
    cout<<"Costo: "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.costo);
    cout<<"Formato: "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,da.formato);
};

void PELICULAS::mostrar(){
    cout<<"PELICULA EXISTENTE"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<da.titulo<< endl;
    cout<< da.clasificacion<< endl;
    cout<< da.duracion<<endl;
    cout<<da.horario<<endl;
    cout<<da.costo<<endl;
    cout<<da.formato<<endl;
};

int main(){
    PELICULAS datos;
    datos.capturar();

    PELICULAS datos1;
    datos.mostrar();

       system("PAUSE");
       system("CLS");
       cout<<endl;

   return 0;


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [answer], en la comunidad esperamos que las respuestas no sean solo código sino que además vengan acompañadas de una exlicación que les haga mas útiles a todos quienes consulten